# bytes() initializer adding an additional byte?

Tags: python-3.x, utf-8

I initialize a utf-8 encoding string in python3:

```
bytes('\xc2', encoding="utf-8", errors="strict")
```

but on writing it out I get two bytes!

```
>>> s = bytes('\xc2', encoding="utf-8", errors="strict")
>>> s
b'\xc3\x82'
```

Where is this additional byte coming from?  Why should I not be able to encode any hex value up to 254 (I can understand that 255 is potentially reserved to extend to utf-16)?

Comment: In all languages (not just python) all codepoints over 0x7F (U+007F) use more than one byte in UTF-8; see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Description

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Unicode codepoint `"\xc2"` (which can also be written as `"Â"`), is two bytes long when encoded with the `utf-8` encoding. If you were expecting it to be the single byte `b'\xc2'`, you probably want to use a different encoding, such as `"latin-1"`:

```
>>> s = bytes("\xc2", encoding="latin-1", errors="strict")
>>> s
b'\xc2'
```

If you area really creating `"\xc2"` directly with a literal though, there's no need to mess around with the `bytes` constructor to turn it into a `bytes` instance. Just use the `b` prefix on the literal to create the bytes directly:

```
s = b"\xc2"
```

Comment: just using the `b` prefix is exactly what i was looking for.  thank you, @Blckknght