# Different interpretation of hex strings in python

Tags: python, string, hex, byte, encode

In the past few days, I've been struggling to understand why this piece of codes behaves in such a way:

**code:**

```
file1 = open("input.txt","r")
M = file1.read()
file1.close()
print(M)
print(M.encode("latin"))
print(type(M.encode("latin")))
print("\n-----------------------------\n")
t = "\xAC\x42\x4C\x45\x54\x43\x48\x49\x4E\x47\x4C\x45\x59"
print(t)
print(t.encode("latin"))
print(type(t.encode("latin")))
```

**file "input.txt" content:**

```
\xAC\x42\x4C\x45\x54\x43\x48\x49\x4E\x47\x4C\x45\x59
```

**output:**

```
\xAC\x42\x4C\x45\x54\x43\x48\x49\x4E\x47\x4C\x45\x59
b'\\xAC\\x42\\x4C\\x45\\x54\\x43\\x48\\x49\\x4E\\x47\\x4C\\x45\\x59'
<class 'bytes'>

-----------------------------

¬BLETCHINGLEY
b'\xacBLETCHINGLEY'
<class 'bytes'>
```

What I don't understand is why the same string is interpreted in 2 different ways, if I read it from the file or if I copy it (by hands) in a variable.
I know that the double "\" is probably the result of me printing the string to the console, but I cannot understand what is happening.

Comment: Here you are fundamentally confusing two things. In your text file, you have `\xAC\x42\x4C\x45\x54\x43\x48\x49\x4E\x47\x4C\x45\x59`, so *literally those characters*. in **Python source code**, string literals understand these back-space + x combination as *an escape sequence*. Similarly, if you write `hello\nworld` in a text file, and load it in python and print it, you'll see `hello\nworld` on the same line, but if your source code contains `print("hello\nworld")` you will see it `hello` then on another line `world`

Comment: IOW, these are *two completely different strings*. In one, you've used a string literal with escape sequences to particular unicode characters, `t = "\xAC\x42\x4C\x45\x54\x43\x48\x49\x4E\x47\x4C\x45\x59"`, in the other, `M` you have the a string *which happens to represent that same source code*. But that won't make python magically execute this string. The same, if you write in a text file `[1,2,3]` and load it in the same way as `M`, then `type(M)` will be `str`, not magically `list` because *strings are not source code*. You would need to use `eval`

Comment: Solved it! Thanks again, I needed to understand the basics and your comment was very clear! Much appreciated.